Noncompetes when the company doesn't have a product (EU)
There is a question that asks for something similar, but the accepted answer is a one-liner. The other answer doesn't quite answer it. I want an answer that feels more complete than either of those.
I was for a while a CTO in a company where I had falling out with the CEO before we managed to create a functioning product. It's been a while, and they still haven't succeeded in making their tech work. I have been considering creating my own device, but I am still under a non-compete for another year.
This leads to my question; Can you violate a noncompete clause with a company that is not actively competing? I always assumed that obviously this must be the case.

united-states

Can you violate a noncompete clause with a company that is not
actively competing?

No.
There are many reasons that a no-compete clause might be invalid. Many states, most notably, California, strongly limit them. The Federal Trade Commission, likewise, just enacted a rule greatly limiting the use of non-competes.
But if you have an otherwise valid non-competition clause the fact that the counterparty (i.e. the former employer) in that contract isn't currently competing with a particular technology or firm doesn't invalidate the contract or render it void.
Also, keep in mind that a non-disclosure agreement or assignment of intellectual property rights to the employer, while often found in the same document as a non-competition agreement, isn't the same thing.
Non-disclosure agreements necessary to protect trade secrets are valid subject to some federally created statutory exceptions in the Defend Trade Secrets Act.
An assignment of intellectual property rights to the employer is normally irrevocable.

Note that the question is tagged european-union, so US laws are not directly on point, although there may be analogous EU statutes.

@TripeHound My comment was before (and probably prompted) the addition of the  united-states tag to the answer.

@Barmar Sorry... forgot to check the timeline.
